# Where are user GNOME desktop favorites settings saved

Tags: gnome, favorites

Ubuntu 22.04, default GNOME desktop.

As a user I can configure my desktop.  In particular I can mark applications as "Favorites" so that they show up on the "launcher sidebar".

Where exactly are these settings saved?  It must save which things I have favorited and the order I have them on the sidebar, presumably in a file somewhere inside `~/.`*something*.  I have tried Googling and had a brief look at files/folders there but cannot spot which one.

Comment: [This answer on stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405276/345853) provides the answer and methods to access it.

Comment: Thanks, sorry, that did not come up in my Google or when I posted this topic here!